# Creating Batch file to copy file which starts with 'ABC' and ends with 'Current' to another folder

Tags: windows

I have a requirement in which I have to create a batch file to copy files in a folder that starts with 'ABC' and ends with Current.xls.

for ex:

the files are in the folder

```
C:\\Sample\Source

ABC Great outdoors Current.xls
ABC Great outdoors Previous.xls
ABC Treading corp  Current.xls
```

I want to copy the files which starts with ABC and ends with Current to a new folder..

I tried using the xcopy command but I don't know how to search for the filenames.

Answer (score 4):

```
copy C:\Sample\Source\ABC*Current.xls targetfolder
```

Comment: Oops.  I gave a different, and fairly complex answer, then remembered that the copy works on multiple files if you provide the wildcard (*).  :)  +1